# VS Code shows 'JSX element type 'MdxBlogPost' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)' when importing an MDX file in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, mdxjs

I want to setup a website with NextJS, TypeScript and mdx-js. I used `yarn create next-app` to setup the project, then added typescript and mdx-js. I created a simple MDX file and imported it in index.tsx. When I run `yarn dev`, the projects builds just fine and I can see the results in the browser.

As the structure of MDX files is not understood by the TS compiler initially, I created a global.d.ts file that tells that the default export of a loaded MDX file provides a JSX.Element:

```js
declare module '*.mdx' {
    declare const component: JSX.Element;
    export default component;
}
```

However, VS Code shows error ts2604 in the editor when I want to render the imported component in index.tsx:

[image: ts2604 when rendering component]

I really don't understand what VS is complaining about, when I write react components and later import them elsewhere, I always use `JSX.Element` as the return type of a function component. And as stated before, next builds work just fine.

What I have tried so far:

- adding `import React from 'react'` in index.tsx or in global.d.ts does not solve the problem.
- changing the type to `ReactNode` (as e.g. done in [this blog post](https://magrippis.com/blog/2020/how-to-setup-MDX-in-Nextjs)) produces the same error in VS.
- when I simply `export default any;` from global.d.ts, the error goes away obviously but I loose type support, which should not really be the goal.
- of course, when adding / changing the d.ts file, I added it to tsconfig.json and restarted VS Code several times to be sure the TS language server is re-initialized properly.

How should a proper TS module declaration look like for MDX files? You can find an MCVE for this question at https://github.com/feO2x/nextjs-ts-mdx

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The correct type of React Components is `React.ComponentType`

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you so much! Need to learn more about the react typings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as [Ajeet Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2873538/) said in the comments, my error was to use `JSX.Element` instead of `React.ComponentType`.

The module declaration should look like this:

```js
declare module '*.mdx' {
    import React from 'react';
    declare const component: React.ComponentType;
    export default component;
}
```